# Dictionary in Swift, Mapping Enum Key to Function Call

Tags: ios, swift

First off, I apologise if I'm asking the impossible, but I swear I've seen this be done before and I'd love to learn how to program like this as it looked cool.

I'm teaching myself Swift (and iOS development) and I've hit a wall as I understand that Swift *should* allow me to do something that I cannot presently do. I've read the Apple documentation on closures but haven't been able to replicate something that I've seen implemented.

I want to create a dictionary that maps an Enum type to a function call. 
i.e.

`var dict = [MyEnumType: {SomeFuncCall}]()`

So when I lookup `MyEnumType.Whatever` it runs the function associated with that key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func method1() {
    println("Method one")
}

func method2() {
    println("Method two")
}

enum MyEnum {
    case One
    case Two
}

typealias Methods = (() -> Void)

var methodDict = [MyEnum: Methods]()
methodDict[MyEnum.One] = method1
methodDict[MyEnum.Two] = method2

methodDict[MyEnum.Two]?()
methodDict[MyEnum.One]?()
```

Output:

```
Method two
Method one
```

Comment: In Swift 2, Xcode 7.2.1, the `typealias` was crucial to get the compiler to recognize the function as a value of a Dictionary in the property declaration/initialization. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a normal lookup you get back a function which is wrapped in an `Optional` so in order to call it you would have to do the following (using optional chaining):

```
let optionalFunc: (()->())? = dict[MyEnumType.Whatever]
optionalFunc?() // the function gets called if it is not nil

// or direcly call it after the lookup
dict[MyEnumType.Whatever]?()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno why you're using an enum there. But it *sounds* like it should be pretty easy to do what you're looking for. First off, if you had just `Int`s instead of enums:

```
let myDict = [
  1:{print(1)},
  2:{print(2)},
  3:{print(3)},
  4:{print(4)}
]

myDict[1]?()
```

So to retrieve the value for a given key, you use the standard dictionary syntax. Then, you need the `?` for optional chaining, since the value may not be returned, and then finally, you need `()`, because what's returned is a closure, which you call with `()`.

To use an enum, you'd need to make it `Hashable`.

Comment: Enums can be used as keys with no problems using the latest beta :D

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. excuse my for the random names:)

```
    class SomeClass
{
    func test(parameter : Double) -> Double
    {
     return 21.2
    }
    enum SomeEnum
    {
        case a(Double -> Double)
    }
    var someDictionary : [String : SomeEnum] = [:]

    init()
    {
        someDictionary["a"] = SomeEnum.a(test)
    }
}
var lol = SomeClass()
lol.someDictionary["a"]
```